# Will client JVM for a web service(https) throw an SSL Exception when the server is having a valid certificate from a CA?

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificate

I have a web service deployed on tomcat hosted on a remote server. 
I have set it up such that it can be accessed only via HTTPS.
For this, I generated a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and used it to get a temporary certificate from VeriSign.

My web service client is on my local machine. If I try to access the service it will throw a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
If I install the certificate in to local Java's keystore, the issue will be resolved.

My question is if I install a valid SSL certificate from a CA in to my tomcat server,
will I get this client-side error even if I do not import the certificate to local key store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't. JVM ships with root ca's by default. The older JVMs (1.5.xx version) don't have all root CA's, but if you have a certificate from Verisign it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Java has many root CA certificates already installed. As long as you use one of those popular CAs to get your certificate, the client will not receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

While you *should* be fine, its a good idea to include not only the actual certificate for your site, but also the entire chain leading up to the root certificate.  (Sometimes you'll bump into clients which are missing some intermediate certificates and this can cause annoying debugging problems.)